# Laravel sum() method on collection returning results for all items in table

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

Given the following table

```
gallery
+----+---------------+--------------+---------+
| id | gallery_title |   viewcount  | user_id |
+----+---------------+--------------+---------+
|  1 | Animals       |           10 |       1 |
|  2 | Cars          |            5 |       1 |
|  3 | Houses        |            2 |       2 |
+----+---------------+--------------+---------+

user
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Bob      |
|  2 | James    |
+----+----------+
```

and the following classes

```
class Gallery extends Model
    ....    
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

and

```
class User extends Model
    ....
    public function galleries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Gallery');
    }
```

calling `$galleryCollections= Auth::user()->galleries;` returns an array of collections in which I can iterate through

```
foreach ($galleryCollections as $galleryCollection)
{
    $viewcount += $galleryCollection->viewcount;
}

print $viewcount; #returns 15
```

and so far everything works as expected, correctly up until this point.

However if I **accidentally** called `$galleryCollection->sum('viewcount')`, which is the last value from the iteration, the returned value is 17, as it's simply running the following SQL `select sum('viewcount') as aggregate from 'gallery'`.

I'm struggling to understand what exactly what is happening here.  It's almost as if it's calling the 'sum()' method on the gallery class itself without passing in any 'where' values.  I'd at least expect it to call the sum() method on the Collection, but instead it's going back to the database.

Is it because my Gallery class does not implement a 'sum()' method, and therefore it uses the Parent Model class and ignores the Gallery class?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count through sql, then:

```
Auth::user()->galleries()->sum('viewCount');
```

But, `Auth::user()->galleries->sum('viewCount');` will sum on the collection `Auth::user()->galleries`.
`Auth::user()->galleries()` is a queryBuilder whereas `Auth::user()->galleries` is a collection of galleries of that user.